# Spring webflow Value of second parameter is not passed to subflow

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-webflow

Hi, I am using spring webflow2.4.4 with spring4.1.3.
 I am trying to pass values between two flows as below.
sending value from flow first xml

```
<action-state id="submit">
        <evaluate expression="someMethod(form)" result="flowScope.saveStatus" />
        <set name="flowScope.value1" value="form.value1" />
        <set name="flowScope.value2" value="form.value2" />
        <transition on="success" to="view" />
    </action-state>

    <subflow-state id="view" subflow="flow/path/view">
        <input name="value1" value="value1" />
        <input name="value2" value="value2" />
        ...
    </subflow-state>
```

reeving data in flow second view xml

```
<input name="value1" type="string" />
    <input name="value2" type="string" />
```

now in view xml I am able to receive value for "value1" what I passed from first flow but getting value for 'value2' is null.

I tried switching the position in first flow as below

```
<action-state id="submit">
        <evaluate expression="someMethod(form)" result="flowScope.saveStatus" />
        <set name="flowScope.value2" value="form.value2" />
        <set name="flowScope.value1" value="form.value1" />
        <transition on="success" to="view" />
    </action-state>

    <subflow-state id="view" subflow="flow/path/view">
        <input name="value2" value="value2" />
        <input name="value1" value="value1" />
        ...
    </subflow-state>
```

Now I am able to see value of 'value2' but value for 'value1' receiving is null.

What is wrong here? see below debug logs for both example

1st trial

*DEBUG SubflowState - Calling subflow 'flow/path/view' with input map['value1' -> 'ABCDF', 'value2' -> [null]]*

2nd trial

*DEBUG SubflowState - Calling subflow 'flow/path/view' with input map['value2' -> 'ABCDF', 'value1' -> [null]]*

I want to pass both thew values to second flow but it second parameter is getting skipped somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks rptmat57, below code worked for me.

```
<action-state id="submit">
    <evaluate expression="someMethod(form)" result="flowScope.saveStatus" />
    <transition on="success" to="view" >
        <set name="flowScope.value2" value="form.value2" />
        <set name="flowScope.value1" value="form.value1" />
    </transition>
</action-state>
```

Answer (score 2):

this is a very common mistake. the action state is transitioning when it gets a success and stops evaluating the rest of the commands.

you need to use `<on-entry>` to separate the two:

1. the commands you want to set or evaluate (value1 & value2)
2. the command that will be evaluated for the transition, here someMethod(form))

**use this instead:**

```
<action-state id="submit">
    <on-entry>
        <set name="flowScope.value2" value="form.value2" />
        <set name="flowScope.value1" value="form.value1" />
    </on-entry>
    <evaluate expression="someMethod(form)" result="flowScope.saveStatus" />
    <transition on="success" to="view" />
</action-state>
```

Comment: Thanks, but what is values if value1 and value2 are dependent on evaluating expression?

Comment: then what do you want your action state to evaluate to "success"? split whatever you are doing into 2 method: `processValues()` and `evaluateResult()` and have the first one be in the `<on-entry>`

Comment: there are often multiple ways of doing things with webflow